# Counting characters that print, not processed, in a string

Tags: python, special-characters

Dealing with an annoying issue using foreign characters (ģ,č,ŗ,ļ,ā,ē,ū,ī,ņ,š,ķ,ž and their capitals). They all have length using `len` not equal to 1, for example `len('ī')` is 2 (it shows up as `\xc4\xab` when processing text). I would like a function that gives back 1 for all those characters. Any help?

Comment: The return value of `len` for unicode characters is going to be system dependent.

Comment: @Jared Well, I'm using Mac OS 10.7.5, and the implementation is in Sage

Comment: [Pragmatic Unicode -or- How Do I Stop The Pain?](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html)

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to Robᵩ for the explanatory webpage. A concise solution to my problem:

```
def varlen(string):
    return len(string.decode('utf-8'))
```